# form input with autonumber yii2 something wrong

Tags: forms, yii, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-basic-app

I've tried to make form input with autonumber using extensions mdmsoft/yii2-autonumber. And the result in my browser this bellow.
[image] 
And this my code form in view.

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Donatur */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="donatur-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'kode_donatur')->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'value' => 'kode_donatur']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'nama_donatur')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'alamat')->textArea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'telepon')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Simpan' : 'Ubah', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?php
  echo "&nbsp";
  echo "&nbsp"; 
  echo Html::a('Keluar', ['index'],['class'=>'btn btn-primary']);
  ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

And I want autonumber display in textfield "Kode donatur". An example can be seen in the image below.
[image]

Code in controller

```html
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Donatur;
use app\models\SearchDonatur;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * DonaturController implements the CRUD actions for Donatur model.
 */
class DonaturController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Donatur models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new SearchDonatur();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Donatur model.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Donatur model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Donatur();
        if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
            $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
            if ($model->save()) {
                \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Data berhasil disimpan!');
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Data gagal disimpan!');
            }
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
            return $this->refresh();

        }
        else {
            return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);    
        }  
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Donatur model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = Donatur::findOne($id);

        if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
            $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
            if ($model->save()) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Data berhasil diupdate!');
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Data gagal diupdate!');
            }
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
            return $this->refresh();
        }
        else {
            return $this->render('update', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Donatur model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($kode_donatur)
    {
        $model = Donatur::findOne($kode_donatur);
        $model->delete();
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('delete', 'Data berhasil dihapus!');
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Donatur model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param string $id
     * @return Donatur the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Donatur::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }

}
```

Code in model

```html
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Donatur extends ActiveRecord
{
 public static function tableName()
 {
  return 'donatur';
 }

 public function rules()
 {
  return [
      [['nama_donatur', 'alamat', 'telepon'], 'required'],
      [['kode_donatur', 'nama_donatur', 'alamat'], 'string'],
      [['telepon'], 'integer'],
      ];
 }

 public function behaviors()
    {
    return [
        [
            'class' => 'mdm\autonumber\Behavior',
            'attribute' => 'kode_donatur', // required
            //'group' => $this->id_branch, // optional
            'value' => 'D'.'?' , // format auto number. '?' will be replaced with generated number
            'digit' => 4 // optional, default to null. 
        ],
    ];
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Where you generate auto number?.show code

Comment: Show your related action code .. please

Answer (score 0):

Your behaviours() function is not in the model it should be in your controller.Like this,

```
 public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['POST'],
            ],
        ],
        [
          'class' => 'mdm\autonumber\Behavior',
        'attribute' => 'kode_donatur', // required
        //'group' => $this->id_branch, // optional
        'value' => 'D'.'?' , // format auto number. '?' will be replaced with generated number
        'digit' => 4 // optional, default to null. 
        ],
    ];
}
```